# Facebook API: How to update the status?

Tags: facebook

How can I update my facebook tatus messages through the API?

There are a lot of examples around the net but all of they seem to be deprecated with the New Facebook API.

Regards!

Comment: You may want to tag/specify a programming language so users can give you a code example using the API native to that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A status message is now just a post. So you using the Graph API to publish a post to the user. You basically just need to do an HTTP POST to http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed. The POST body should contain the value for the message. If you want the status to change you must only set the message. Here is how you would do it with curl.

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

You can find more information about this here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

Comment: I'm having trouble with access_token, access_token must be obtained before setting up a new status message? I want my application to update users status without their login, they will trigger it remotely.

Comment: If you want to update the user's status without an active session you must request the "offline_access" extended permission when your client authenticates with your app. If you have the offline_access permission, the access token will never expire, so you can store it and use it whenever you need.

Comment: Is there any working PHP example that I can find? I can't find any

Comment: This page has everything you will need for authentication: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I guess I think how to do it... first I obtain the CODE and then I use the CODE to obtain the ACCESS_TOKEN. After this token, I have all that it takes to post in users wall.

Comment: The facebook API has been modified since this question has been posted, google redirecting to this SO page, its status may be updated with the latest API release by facebook (21st Sep 2021).

Answer (score 1):

Using **javascript graph api** sdk also it is possible

```
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
    alert("error");
    } else {
     alert("Status posted");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//Get the access token and secret.and check if true than write below code in your condition

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=" + oAuth.Token;

json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.POST, url, "message=" + msg);
```